# How to add after method works in linked list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, data-structures, linked-list

```
 class ListNode
{
    public object Data { get; private set; }

    public ListNode Next { get; set; }

    public ListNode(object Element)
    {
        Data = Element;
    }

    public ListNode(object Element, ListNode NextNode)
    {
        Data = Element;
        Next = NextNode;
    }

    public ListNode()
    {

    }
}

 class LinkedList
{
    ListNode first;
    ListNode last;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        first = null;
        last = null;
    }


   public ListNode Find(object After)
    {
        ListNode current = new ListNode();
        current= first;
        while (current.Data != After)
        current = current.Next;
        return current;
    }

   public void Add(object newItem, object After)
   {
       ListNode current=new ListNode();
       ListNode newNode=new ListNode();
       current = Find(After);
       newNode.Next = current.Next;
       current.Next = newNode;
   }

    public void InsertAtFront(object Element)
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
        {
            first = last = new ListNode(Element);
        }
        else
        {
            first = new ListNode(Element,first);
        }
    }

    bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return first == null;
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        ListNode current = first;
        while (current!=null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(current.Data);
            current = current.Next;
        }           
    }
}
```

I implement Find method for Add After specific element, but when I debug it showing me the object reference not set to an instance of an object exception. Please point out my mistake in Find method or with Add After method. thanks

Comment: Homework? If not, just use `List<object>`.

Comment: You might want to consider getting rid of some of the unneeded `ListNode` initialisations. i.e. change `current = Find(After);`
 to `ListNode current = Find(After);` which'd allow you to get rid of `ListNode current=new ListNode();` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here

```
while (current.Data != After)
      current = current.Next;
```

When there is no After in your list you will eventually get `current.Next` equal to `null`
You need to  check if current.Next  is not null

```
   while (current.Next != null && current.Data != After)
      current = current.Next;
```

you should also fix your add logic (if you want to add elements into empty list)

```
   public void Add(object newItem, object After)
   {
       if(IsEmpty())
       {
            InsertAtFront(newItem);
            return;
       }

       ListNode newNode=new ListNode();
       newNode.Data = newItem; 
       ListNode current = Find(After);
       newNode.Next = current.Next;
       current.Next = newNode;
   }
```

Comment: still the same problem exists

Answer (score 3):

```
   current= first;
   while (current.Data != After)
```

can result in a potential null reference issue. first can still be set to null from the constructor initialisation which would mean that current = null, which'd then result in null.Data which would throw a null reference exception.

This would fix the null reference issue in Find()

```
   while (current != null && current.Data != After)
```

Fixing this would result in null being returned which would still result in issues in `Add`

```
   current = Find(After);
   newNode.Next = current.Next;
   current.Next = newNode;
```

In this context, `LinkedList` is first initialised, `current = Find(After)` would mean current = null, causing another null reference exceptions on the next two lines.

```
    public void Add(object newItem, object After)
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
        {
            InsertAtFront(newItem);
            return;
        }

        ListNode newNode = new ListNode();
        ListNode current = Find(After);
        newNode.Next = current.Next;
        current.Next = newNode;
    }
```

This will fix both the `Add` and the `Find` methods to be usable in the form of:

```
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    list.InsertAtFront("test");
    list.Find(list.first.Data);
    list.Add("test2", ll.first.Data);
```

This will make it workable, but I would however highly recommend reading into the implementation of linked lists or using one of the system collections as this implementation has quite a few potential issues.